# How to disdepend svg from the container width and height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, sass

I have a question that bothers me. I have a problem with SVG image, that depends on the container (div) size, but it parent is another div. Here's the images which describe the relationship: [first img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zItOh.png); [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWggt.png); and [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtMc.png). When container size is set to 100%, the #cover also resizes from the svg box and conversely. Do you know how to solve it?

```css
#container{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;height: 100%; // When size is set to 100%, the darker side disappears from the svg box
}

.color-switcher{
   display: flex;
   width: 100%;height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <!--  color switcher  -->
  <div class="color-switcher">
    <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1103 658">
      <defs>
        <style>
          .cls-1{fill:#32375e;}
          .cls-2{fill:#484e82;}
          .cls-3{fill:#454a75;}
          .cls-4{fill:#545b94;}
        </style>
      </defs>
      <title>setting-chest</title>
      <g id="chest">
        <rect id="container-shadow" class="cls-1" width="1103" height="658" rx="65.56"/>
        <circle id="nut1" class="cls-2" cx="78" cy="78" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut1-2" class="cls-2" cx="78" cy="558" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut1-3" class="cls-2" cx="1003" cy="558" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut1-4" class="cls-2" cx="1003" cy="78" r="34"/>
      </g>
      <g id="Cover">
        <rect id="container" class="cls-2" width="1082" height="636" rx="64.65"/>
        <circle id="nut" class="cls-1" cx="78" cy="78" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut-2" class="cls-1" cx="78" cy="558" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut-3" class="cls-1" cx="1003" cy="558" r="34"/>
        <circle id="nut-4" class="cls-1" cx="1003" cy="78" r="34"/>
        <rect id="box-shadow" class="cls-3" x="349" y="178" width="421" height="288" rx="42.71"/>
        <rect id="box-shadow-2" class="cls-4" x="342" y="171" width="421" height="288" rx="42.71"/>
        <path id="wheel" class="cls-1" d="M627.56,330.18h0l-11-10.13a71.34,71.34,0,0,0,0-18l11-10.16a10.88,10.88,0,0,0,2-13.29l-12.16-21a10.79,10.79,0,0,0-12.59-4.89l-14.3,4.52a65.29,65.29,0,0,0-15.59-9.05l-3.31-14.69A10.77,10.77,0,0,0,561.18,225H536.81a10.78,10.78,0,0,0-10.45,8.39l-3.3,14.69a65,65,0,0,0-15.59,9l-14.32-4.52a10.8,10.8,0,0,0-12.54,4.85L468.4,278.57a10.87,10.87,0,0,0,2.06,13.28l11,10.13a71.34,71.34,0,0,0,0,18L470.4,330.14a10.88,10.88,0,0,0-2,13.29l12.16,21a10.79,10.79,0,0,0,12.58,4.9l14.31-4.52a64.77,64.77,0,0,0,15.59,9l3.3,14.68a10.78,10.78,0,0,0,10.45,8.4h24.37a10.77,10.77,0,0,0,10.44-8.39l3.31-14.69a65,65,0,0,0,15.59-9l14.32,4.52a10.75,10.75,0,0,0,12.54-4.86l12.22-21.11A10.86,10.86,0,0,0,627.56,330.18ZM549,346.83A35.83,35.83,0,1,1,584.83,311,35.83,35.83,0,0,1,549,346.83Z"/></g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "depends on it"? Do you mean the width of the SVG is equal to the width of `#container`? What do you want the width to be? Also is your javascript code relevant? Consider reducing your snippet until it only has minimum code needed to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Also, regarding your "so you have to convert it": Please convert it yourself, _for us._ Most people will disregard your question since we don't want to work for a question, but want to be able to answer it immediately. By converting it yourself, you spare us the work that _each one of us_ would otherwise have to do, making it more likely that you will get answers.

Comment: Okay, it's my fail, I just didn't noticed one thing, the topic ended.